# Ethereum - rpcaddr 0.0.0.0

Tags: ethereum

I have an ethereum which has a set up of :
   rpcaddr 0.0.0.0 --rpcport 8545 --rpcapi "web3,eth,net,db" --rpccorsdomain "*"

Since rpcaddr is 0.0.0.0 which is avaialble to all IP that wants to, is it safe if we restrict only 1 ip address to access it using inbound rules? so other IP address can't transact using 8545.

Comment: Another way would be setting `rpcaddr 127.0.0.1` and run a local smart contract API (using web3), which you then access from remote via some `Auth` method.